# Pandas rename one value as other value in a column and add corresponding values in the other column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

So, I have a pandas data frame:

```
        df = 
                 a                   b          c
                 a1                 b1         c1
                 a2                 b2         c1
                 a2                 b3         c2
                 a2                 b4         c2
```

I want to rename `a2` into `a1` and then group by `a` and `c` and add the corresponding values of `b`

```
       df =
                a                  b           c
                a1                 b1+b2       c1
                a1                 b3+b4       c2
```

So, something like this

```
      df  =
                a               value           c
                a1              10              c1
                a2              20              c1
                a2              50              c2
                a2              60              c2

      df  =
               a                value            c
               a1               30               c1
               a1               110              c2
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
>>> res = df.replace({"a": {"a2": "a1"}}).groupby(["a", "c"], as_index=False).sum()
>>> res

    a   c  value
0  a1  c1     30
1  a1  c2    110
```

which first replaces `"a2"`s with `"a1"` in only `a` column and then groups by and sums.

To get the original column order back, we can `reindex`:

```
>>> res.reindex(df.columns, axis=1)

    a  value   c
0  a1     30  c1
1  a1    110  c2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df.groupby([df['a'].replace({'a2':'a1'}),'c']).sum().reset_index()
```